# dynamic validation and error messages

Tags: angularjs, validation

I would like to create generic error messages for the various validation error conditions in angular. I do this by evaluating `field.$error`.

For instance if `$error.email` is present, the validation failed due to the field not being a valid email.

Currently the value for `minlength` is true.

It would be useful to be able to dynamically discover what the `minlength` was set to.

My thoughts at the moment are to ensure that the name and the id are the same, then find by `id` using `field.$name` from there get the value of `ng-minlength`.

That seems really messy. Is there a better way?

Comment: What have you done so far??? Post your code...

Comment: I've been thinking about it and I will probably just look at overriding the existing directives and when the value is shorter than the min add $error.minlength = theValue instead of true. This would be far more useful for generic messages. Will probably also make a suggestion to the angular dev team.